# Android Library - Using multiple flavor and combining them

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I'm building a library on Android and I need many different flavors.

Each flavor may or may not have special dependencies but each of them have at least one classes associated with it.

*Each are working individually.*

**1)** Now some of my flavors are basically a sum of other flavors. (flavorC is exactly flavorA's dependencies and sources and flavorB's dependencies and sources)

I couldn't find a way to declare this in my build.gradle so I'm duplicating things, and I hate duplicating things :)

Could someone point me out how to do it?

**2)** I also have another issue, right now I can only do "gradlew assembleFlavorARelease" when I want to build flavorA.

If I want to build all the flavor at the same time I can't use "gradlew assembleRelease", since calling it will build the flavorA's lib.aar, then override it with flavorB's lib.aar etc...

Is it possible to specify an output for the artefacts? Or a different name maybe?

**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Android studio 1.0 this is now done automatically.